# Curved border with stroke in pure CSS?

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to achieve a curved border (with a stroke) using only CSS? At the moment I'm creating curved borders for the header of my website using images:

[image: Curved Border Using Images]

I'd like to change this to a CSS solution so that I'm not having to alter images when the amount of content within changes - I need these to be dynamic and responsive, I've managed to draw a curve using border-radius:

[image: Curved Border Using CSS]

This works much better for me, but I'm wondering if it is possible to add a stroke to it to make it look a more like the image representation? Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the code I've written to achieve this:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
  background: #21639e;
}
.slider .slide {
  background: url("image.jpg") no-repeat #21639e;
  border-radius: 100%/0 0 30px 30px;
}
```

I did try adding `border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;` to the .slide class, but it ended up looking like this:

[image: Curved Border Using CSS with Border]

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwda1u3y/1/) for you to test what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you please paste a working snippet?

Comment: Updated with a working snippet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can try and use box shadows to create this kind of border. Applying a white box shadow on the outer side of the element will make it look like a stroke/border.

This - `border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;` produces a different kind of effect because we are applying only the bottom border to the element. The borders on the left and right are non existent (***zero width***) and so the line thins out as you go nearer to the edges.

```css
.slider {
  height: 500px;
  background: #21639e;
}
.slider .slide {
  height: 200px;  
  background: url("http://placehold.it/800x800/FF00FF") no-repeat #21639e;
  border-radius: 100%/0 0 30px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is an updated version of your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwda1u3y/2/).

---

For a more graceful looking curve then you can also try the below approach. It uses a pseudo element which is wider than the `.slide` and then centers the image within it. (*I feel that this approach makes it look closer to the original image but the choice is yours*)

```css
.slider {
  height: 500px;
  background: #21639e;
}
.slider .slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider .slide:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -2%;
  top: -6px;
  width: 104%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/800x800/FF00FF") no-repeat center center #21639e;
  border-radius: 100%/0 0 30px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I was just discussing with my manager about how we could make the curve bend more towards the outside (like in my image), so your additional approach is extremely helpful! I'm going to implement that now.

Comment: What does `border-radius: 100%/0 0 30px 30px;` exactly do? I know how a border radius works but I've never seen percent dividet by the radius before. How does this work?

Comment: @Demnogonis It represents the radius in the two axis when / is used. When not used, the same value applies for both axes. I'm away from my desk, will give you a link with more info when I get back to my PC.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but the percentage looks to be vertical axis, after that percentage, it's top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left (radius).

Comment: This `100%/0 0 30px 30px` is actually equivalent to `100% 100% 100% 100%/0 0 30px 30px`. That is the radii for top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left are 100% in the X-axis and `0 0 30px 30px` in Y-axis. 0 radius for Y-axis in top-left and top-right would mean the curve has no height (not the right choice of words but you get what I mean) and so you don't get to see any curve at the top. 30px radius in Y-axis for b-r and b-l means the curve at the bottom is an ellipse with height of 30px and 100% in Y-axis means the ellipse's width is equal to width of the element.

Comment: @Demnogonis: Here is the link to the specs - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-border/#the-border-radius.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that you could manipulate the individual axis of the border-radius. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Comment: @LiamMcArthur Changes to another person's code are frowned upon, as that causes the answer to deviate from the author's intent. Especially for changes of opinion, such as whether to write `px` or not for CSS property values of 0.

Comment: Ahh my bad! I have a habit for picking up on that when I see 0px :)