# Curved header with pure CSS

Tags: css

Trying to nail this curved header with pure CSS but using border radius isn't keeping the left & right border edges as sharp as they are in the image. Any help would be appreciated.[image: Curved header]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609308/curved-border-with-stroke-in-pure-css where are you now? Where is your code that’s not working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, one such thing is using `border-radius`. So, for the shape you just need to have a `border-bottom-left-radius:` and `border-bottom-right-radius:`.

Here I have attached the code,

```css
body{
  background-color:#f3f2f4;
}
.header{
  width:105%;
  height:40%;
  left:-3%;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8459f9, #4c3196);
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
}
.container{
  width:60vw;
  height:80vh;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```