# Slightly curved bottom div in css

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve this type of shape with the help of CSS?

I have tried the following two links but they didn't generate the exact result.

[Curved border with stroke in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609308/curved-border-with-stroke-in-pure-css)

http://jsfiddle.net/ECHWb/

```
.banner-img{
  height: 661px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40% 55px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40% 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. End result should match with the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Try with clip-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom)

Comment: @PEPEGA His code is actually from there, thus it didn't answer his question.

Comment: I recommend using SVG.

Comment: @PEPEGA I have tried this. it doesn't work. I don't want to use SVGs or :after and :before elements

Comment: @DIDIx13 I don't wanna use SVGs. Any other way with CSS?

Comment: @UmerFarooq Yes you can, CSS3 is very powerful: https://9elements.com/blog/css-border-radius/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using CSS `clip-path`!

For example, create a "spacer" div below the actual div with a clip-path property like that `clip-path: ellipse(50% 9% at 50% 50%);`. This will create an elliptic path from the div. Overlapp the top-half of this div with your original one and - tada - you have a rounded bottom.

Try [this tool](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to experiment a little bit with clip-path or see the [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: it worked to some extent. The thing is I have an image in that banner and that banner looks like curved. The way you suggested banner image doesn't look curved. Any idea about that ?

Comment: @UmerFarooq a common workaround could be to use the same image on the "curve" container. This requires some precision though, to make it look smooth on all devices

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SVG for this. Here is an example, I did this some time ago. Unfortunately it's for a footer, so you can't copy-paste it 1:1, but it shows you how it can be done.

```css
.footer-curve__wrapper {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

/*
 just to demonstrate it in combination with another element
*/
footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3ca3a2;
}


/*remove margin-padding from elements in footer*/
footer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="500px">
  Content
</div>
<div class="footer-curve__wrapper">
  <svg class="footer-curve__image" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1600 100"> <defs> <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M0 101.3l1600-1.3V0H0z"></path> </defs> <clipPath id="SVGID_2_"> <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" overflow="visible"></use> </clipPath> <path d="M0 53.6V100h1600V0h-2.9c-237.2 59.2-570.9 96-940.6 96C417.1 96 192.8 80.6 0 53.6" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#38a3a2"></path> </svg>
</div>
<footer>
  <p> Footer text </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: no i don't want to use svg.

Comment: your decision, but if i may ask: Why not? It's supported in every browser. Creating the SVG is the hardest part :D